# Как настроить webpack config при работе с vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue3

Существует следующая структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Возможно ли при данной структуре настраивать конфигурацию webpack?
Если да - то каким образом можно реализовать данную задачу?

Иными словами:
Где необходимо искать следующий файл(или настройки)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нигде не искать. Его нету по умолчанию, создайте и перезапустите сборку
https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js